# Do public Twitter RSS feeds have access limits?

Tags: twitter, rss, feed, limits

Example RSS feed link: http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/twitter.rss

Does anyone know if Twitter limits calls to a public RSS feed? This is not using an API but a simple call to a URL.

I am unable to find anything official (or even speculative). I know the API has access limits of x requests within y minutes. I am wondering if the public RSS feeds follow a similar pattern. I am seeing behavior in a mobile app that makes me think that this may be the case.

Device 1 receives an empty response while device 2 still gets updates for identical feed. Have also seen it on from my computer running a simulator for a while. Simulator stopped getting updates, then I couldn't pull up the feed in a web browser on same machine that was running the simulator. I am suspicious that Twitter is limiting RSS feed access by device. I think this because in the previous example, all RSS feeds were inaccessible form the web browser while the Twitter site was functioning properly in the same web browser.

The RSS URL is being queried every 10 minutes.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You should update to the newer URL as specified by the [API documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline). Your example would become: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=twitter

Comment: Thanks for the different link info. +1 In this case the API is not being used as there is no authenticated user. This is a mobile app for a client who is behind the feed, and they do not wish require the user to log in. That said, the provided link does in fact work in the same manner as the RSS link available from the twitter page. Unfortunately both links produce the same result of access limits in the mobile app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non authenticated (OAuth only) requests rate is 150 per hour.
OAuth requests rate is 350 per hour.
Requests limit rate is per IP address, so I don't think Twitter will deny the request with ONE request every 10 minutes.

The method you mention is public, but the only requests that doesn't have the rate limit are the ones of the search API (which has a little delay versus the 'real time'). Anyway I suggest you to read: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting and http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate_limiting_faq

Comment: Thanks. +1 We did some testing on the behavior and this did turn out to be correct but the mobile app aspect does add a "flavor" to it. It became apparent that there was never an issue over cellular connections no at my home's wi-fi. In our office, the devices were on the office wi-fi. This office, like many others, shares a single IP out to the world. Our web dept does considerable twitter work for clients as well. All this single IP traffic seamed to lead to the rate limit. Best practice regardless of cellular or wi-fi is to implement a caching server which was already a down the road plan.

Comment: Most cellular providers do proxy requests through a small number of IPs so oftentimes they will butt up against rate limits too.

Comment: +1 thanks found out the hard way with a live site that this request limit is there.. Opps.... Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter's web site is a client of their API, so I'm guessing their RSS feeds are also clients of the Twitter API as well. See [this page](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/09/tech-behind-new-twittercom.html) at the Twitter engineering site for more information about this, and also see the Twitter [Rate Limiting FAQ](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate_limiting_faq) for information about rate limiting.